# react-native-elements icons not showing

Tags: react-native

React-Native-Elements icons showing as (?)

What am I doing wrong? The code looks nearly identical to the sample that they provided on their site.

This is what I see (don't mind the middle icon, it's brought in differently):
[image]

Code that I'm using for the left icon:

```
<Icon name='users' type='Feather' size={25} color={tintColor} />
```

Code for the right icon:

```
GamesInProgressTab: {
    screen: GamesInProgressNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
    title: 'Games',
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => ( <Icon name='rocket' type='Entypo' size={25} color={tintColor} /> ),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your `type` prop.

You need to use one of the following names of the supported types

- `material-community`
- `font-awesome`
- `octicon`
- `ionicon`
- `foundation`
- `evilicon`
- `simple-line-icon`
- `zocial`
- `entypo`
- `feather`

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I was using `react native elements` and the Icons were not showing, only displaying Chinese/Japanese type of a font.

**Note:** My app was **React Native CLI** managed and **NOT Expo** managed.

**My Environment:**

`react-native": "0.62.1"`,
`react-native-elements": "^1.2.7"`

Despite being advised that in RN > 0.60 linking is automatic, I had to manually link the vector icons using:

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

Comment: `"react-native": "0.62.1"` ; `"react-native-elements": "^1.2.7"` 

Incredibly frustrating. This did the trick for me as well. You might need to prepend npx in some cases: `npx react-native link react-native-vector-icons`

Comment: this did the trick for me as well. And you need to restart your env afterwards.

Comment: worked for me too after I ran `./gradlew clean`

Comment: iOS working with auto link, but I needed to link for my android project!